# Query for matching multiple keyword and displaying results?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I have a table called cakes that contains the columns: id, title, description, keywords. I also have a table called keywords, with cakes being the parent. The keywords table contains two columns: id and keyword. I need to write the following two queries:

1. If a person types in ingredients such as chocolate, hazelnut, strawberry (could be any number of keywords separated by a comma) I need the query to search for cakes that contain ALL of the keywords and display results. Display ONLY cakes that contain all keywords. If no cake matches, I need a message saying nothing found.
2. I have a label on the search box which says, Find similar cakes. If a person types in Vanilla Raspberry or example, the query needs to locate the cake in the database and match its keywords to the keywords of other cakes and display results. Display ONLY cakes that have the same keywords and a MINIMUM of three keywords that are the same.

Not sure how to write these queries. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: 1. Have you tried using `IN`? 2. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CakeID, CakeName
FROM TableName
WHERE IngredientName IN ('chocolate', 'hazelnut', 'strawberry' )
GROUP BY CakeID, CakeName
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

or if uniqueness was not enforce on ingredients for every cakes, use `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT CakeID, CakeName
FROM TableName
WHERE IngredientName IN ('chocolate', 'hazelnut', 'strawberry' )
GROUP BY CakeID, CakeName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT IngredientName) = 3
```

- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: JW- the keyword search can be any ingredients, not just those ingredients I referenced and not only three. For example: vanilla, bean, chocolate, ganache OR even chocolate, vanilla...I just need the result to display any cake that matches ALL of the search terms the person enters

Comment: did you think of using parameters?